# How do I serialize an object that also contains two ArrayList of objects in Android Studio (Java)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, serialization

I'm pretty new to both Android Studio and Java in general. I want to serialize an object that contains 2 ArrayList of objects and I've seen that there are several methods to achieve this like SharedPreferences but I'm kinda lost rigth now.

The class I want to serialize is this:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
public String userName="";
public float currentBalance=0;
public float totalExpenses=0;
public float totalIncome=0;
public float ocassionalExpenses=0;
public float ocassionalIncome=0;
public float monthlyExpenses=0;
public float monthlyIncome=0;
public ArrayList<Expense> expenses;
public ArrayList<Income> income;

public User(){
    this.expenses=new ArrayList<Expense>();
    this.income =new ArrayList<Income>();


}
```

and both classes Income and Expense look like this

```
public class Expense implements Parcelable, Serializable {

public String name;
public boolean recurring;
public float prize;



public Expense(String name, boolean recurring, float prize){
    this.name=name;
    this.recurring=recurring;
    this.prize=prize;
}

public class Income implements Parcelable, Serializable {
public String name;
public boolean recurring;
public float prize;

public Income(String name, boolean recurring, float prize){
    this.name=name;
    this.recurring=recurring;
    this.prize=prize;
}
```

I wanted to serialize the User Class with the information of both ArrayLists whenever I make any change to either object and to read this information whenever I open the App. How should I aproach this?

Comment: Your approach is not entirely wrong. What specifically do you want to do?

Comment: I wanted to store and read the User object data and all the information that is contained on its AraryLists of objects. Perhaps with a method on User class that can be called from all Activities and fragments on my App since I'm already calling a single static User object from most classes. I've read that you can serialize in Android Studio with diferent ways such as SharedPreferences, Gson, etc but I don't really know how to do it nor the diferences in each aproach

Answer (score 0):

Okay as i understood. Will help you on GSON deserializer library.

First of all add dependency on `build.gradle` as:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
}
```

Then on your main class or on click event of a button test it like:

```
User user = new User(1 L, "halil", "sahin",
    LocalDate.of(1991, Month.JANUARY, 1), new Department(2, "Software Engineering", true));

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setPrettyPrinting()
    .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateAdapter())
    .create();

String jsonString = gson.toJson(user);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, "Result :" + jsonString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The user class is an example. You can adapt yours.

Comment: So, can I just serialize the User class with GSON and the objects included in its ArrayLists will also be serialized or I need to do this with the objects on the List aswell?

Comment: @TulioPD Just pass the user class to GSON. It will automatically serialize other classes by itself.